# null compare in C language

Tags: c

i already have this code in C language, is a string of 15 data delimited by commas the code split the string by comma and store every data in a single variable called array[], the issue is that i have the last data comma if after the last comma there are no data then the variable x15 = 0, but if there are a value after the last , then convert that value to a int. i print the value of the array[15] to verify and this is null, so i out a condition for that but do not work,  the program just break after compiling.

```
 char buf[] ="¶bL0 L3,01,+08590323,-079343001,010215,00000000000000,-tN,000,012689997,001219456,000,7FF2,C07F,0,4,";

printf("\n \n string=[%s]\n\n", buf);
int i = 0;
int u;
char *p = strtok (buf, ",");
char *array[16];
char *y15;
while (p != NULL)
{
    array[i++] = p;
    p = strtok (NULL, ",");
}

for (i = 0; i <16; ++i){
        if(array[15] == NULL){
            wbt.x15=0;
        }else{
        wbt.x15=atoi(array[15]);
        }

//printf("data: [%s]\n", array[i]);
}
```

Comment: Can you rewrite your question? Paragraphs exist for a reason.

Comment: Why not set a reasonable breakpoint, e. g. at the beginning of the `for` loop, along with a watch on `array`, and then step through the program execution? You´d see how the values of the array change and when.

Comment: The program broke after compiling... What did you do once you compiled the program?  Programs don't simply break after compiling, they break in your brain, or when you are writing them.  But if you have compiled a program, it doesn't break spontaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an uninitialized array element, which is cause for undefined behavior.

You have:

```
char *array[16];
```

The elements of the array are uninitialized. And then, you proceed to use:

```
  if(array[15] == NULL){
     wbt.x15=0;
  }else{
     wbt.x15=atoi(array[15]);
  }
```

It's not clear why you have that check for every iteration of the loop but that's another problem. The problem with the posted code is that `array[15]` is not initialized. Using that value is a problem.

Make sure you initialize `array` properly. Use:

```
char *array[16] = {0};
```

Also, I think your `for` loop needs to be something like:

```
for (i = 0; i <16; ++i)
{
   int x = 0;
   if(array[i] != NULL)
   {
      x = atoi(array[i]);
   }

   // Now use x.
}
```

Comment: Based on the way the array is constructed with the `while/strtok` loop, it would seem to me that the `for` loop should just terminate on null: `if (array[i] == NULL) break;`

Comment: thanks you so much, its just simple the initialization of the array. every day we learn in programming, basic things can actually break our head haha.

Comment: @CraigEstey, agree.

Comment: @O.nunez, the comment by Craig is worth taking into account.